# How do I change a sound

Tags: macbook-pro, system-sounds

How do I change a sound when I receive a text on my Macbook pro.  I cannot find it in notifications.  I would like different sounds for each of several applications.  IE: text messages, email, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple forum:

> Message Menu > Preferences > Alerts.
>   Change the top item (which is a drop down) to the action you want.
>   Change Sound in the next item down.
>
> You can use the Application sounds, the System Sounds and any sounds in ~/Library/Sounds
>   These will show up in the list if you have them.
>
> However the Home Folder/Library/Sounds is hidden as the Home folder/Library is hidden
>   Use the Finder > Go Menu > Go to Folder and type in ~/Library/Sounds to see what is in there  (or place new sounds in there).

Comment: Thanks..  So simple, yet so difficult when you are new to IOS

Comment: Yeah, takes some time to get used to UNIX.